# Sorting all Rows in Excel Spreadsheet by Number of Columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, sorting

Anyone know how to do this? I'm not finding anything via Google or any other search.

I have an excel spreadsheet like this

```
 |   A    |    B   |    C   |   D    |   E   |   F    |    G   |
1|  text  |  text  |  text  |  text  | text  |  text  |        |
2|  text  |  text  |  text  |  text  |       |        |        |
3|  text  |  text  |  text  |  text  |       |        |        |
4|  text  |  text  |  text  |  text  | text  |  text  |  text  |
5|  text  |  text  |        |        |       |        |        |
6|  text  |  text  |  text  |  text  | text  |        |        |
```

and I'm looking to sort all my rows based off the number of columns.

As for the above example, the desired output would be:

```
 |   A    |    B   |    C   |   D    |   E   |   F    |    G   |
5|  text  |  text  |        |        |       |        |        |
2|  text  |  text  |  text  |  text  |       |        |        |
3|  text  |  text  |  text  |  text  |       |        |        |
6|  text  |  text  |  text  |  text  | text  |        |        |
1|  text  |  text  |  text  |  text  | text  |  text  |        |
4|  text  |  text  |  text  |  text  | text  |  text  |  text  |
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Add another column with the following formula: `=COUNTA(A1:G1)` or `=COUNTIF(A1:G1,"<>")` then sort that column ascending?

Comment: Tried this but not sure how it would work..  Obviously I'm getting `6` as the output of the formula.... then if I just sort that column... which is just a column in row `H` with the number `6` in `H:1`... sorting that column with just that one row.... not doing anything, so I'm not sure if I'm understanding this correctly

Comment: You need to copy the formula down the dataset, to get the count for each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a helper column:

Put this in H1:

```
=COUNTA(A1:G1)
```

Or, if your data is populated by formula:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:G1,"<>")
```

Then copy/drag the formula down the dataset.

[image]

Then sort the data on that column:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Awesome. Looks like it's going to work.  Give me a minute to try it out :)

Comment: Worked great, very smart solution. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can simply sort by 'column F, then column E, then D, etc.' 
Use ALT+D, S to get in the sort screen, and add the columns from the right to the left.